# How i can return a response if it depends of a Mono object?

Tags: java, spring-boot, reactive-programming

I am new with reactive programing and i need help to understeand this scenario.

```
@autowired
private e;

private Mono<b> method1(list<a> object1){
   
  b object2 = new b();
  c object3 = new c();
  f object5 = new f();

  for (a obj : object1) {
       Mono<d> object4 = e.getD(obj.getSomething(), obj.getSomething2());
      //I need stop this mapping when a condition is Meet and continue the logic downstream 
       object4.map(mapper->{
            int status= mapper.getStatus();
            if(status == 200){
                object2.setSomethingElse(mapper.getValue1());
                object3.setSomethingElse(mapper.getValue2());
               //do something and stop execution
                object5.setSomethingElse2(mapper.getValue3());
            }
            //if that condition is not meet then continue
            //more logic doing other set to other values of object2 and 3
       });

  }
  object3.setF(object5);
  object2.setB(object3);
  return Mono.just(object2);
}
```

the problem is that when i map into the loop i need to return a response but i dont want do it in that moment i want that the loop ends mapping all values of the dependencies objects and then continue the execution of the method. i hope someone understeand me. I repeat i am new with reactive programing so i dont know if i doing something wrong.

Comment: you've anonymized the code quite well so it's not really possible to figure out what is the purpose of this code. however, you should try converting the initial parameter list to reactive list, then flatmap those items to executions and combine the results. but going into more details than that is not possible with this information... we don't know what are these b, c, f objects for.

Answer (score 1):

`Mono.block()` will return the response after the computation is done.

Below code should work.

```
return Mono.just(object2).block();
```